# What word would refer to "fluent in reading"?

Tags: word-request, terminology

What word would you use to refer to "fluency" in reading? The manner which is characterized by your highly infrequent use of dictionaries when reading texts and a good speed. You could say one has a voluminous vocabulary, for example, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Per *[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/fluent)*, the word *fluent* can be used to describe productive (speaking, writing), not receptive skills (listening, reading):

> **1** Able to express oneself easily and articulately. 
> *‘a fluent speaker and writer on technical subjects’*
>
> **1.1** Able to speak or write a particular foreign language easily and accurately. 
> *‘she became fluent in French and German’*
>
> **1.2** (of a foreign language) spoken accurately and with facility. 
> *‘he spoke fluent Spanish’*

Comment: Did you look up 'fluent' in the dictionary? Did it not have examples showing that it can be used this way?

Comment: I don't think there's a common adjective/adverb comparable to "fluent" or "fluently"; I'd just say "I can read French well."

Comment: @Astralbee as per Lexico, the word can be used to describe productive (speaking, writing), not receptive skills (listening, reading)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *fluent reader*, *read fluently* or *fluent in reading* in the context. There isn't a single word for "fluency in reading" (having the ability to read fluently) akin to *articulate* for having the ability to speak fluently.

Example usage:

> Within weeks, she was **a fluent reader.** 
> *The Times Literary Supplement* 
> [*Collins*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fluent-reader)

*Reading fluency* is a type of language fluency along with *oral fluency (or speaking fluency), oral reading fluency* and *written (or compositional fluency).* *Listening fluency* is added in some other contexts or sources.

> Reading fluency refers to the link between the recognition of words while reading and reading comprehension, which manifests itself in the speed and accuracy that one is able to read text. 
>  *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluency)*

There is the technical term *automatic* in the *[automaticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automaticity)* theory in reading but it is used in technical contexts with different meanings. There is also "reading proficiency" under "language proficiency", and some sources say that fluency is a component of it.

---

A bonus rare word:

> **vocabularian** *n.* A person considered in regard to the size or impressiveness of his or her vocabulary; a wordsmith. - *[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/224266#eid15417883)*